# SharePoint hosted App with 'Read' permission to site collection in AppManifest, throws error on deploying.

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am developing an App which reads a List in HostWeb. I have granted Read permission to SiteCollection in AppManifest.

While deploying the app it throws a peculiar JavaScript error -

"JavaScript critical error at line 300 column 32 in "https://abc.sharepoint.com/xyz/_layouts/15/appInv.aspx?AppinstanceId=cvzjxh68-7fsd-f987-sdf70........"

[image]

This error occurs for all permissions be it list or web or site collection anything.

However, if I remove all permissions, then the app is successfully deployed. It is just that it is not able to access the list. Which is obvious, because it does not have the required permission.

Could anybody please advise, what is going wrong.

How can I assign 'Read' permission to sitecollection and then successfully deploy the app.

Comment: You are deploying from Visual Studio with F5, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are experiencing some javascript issues on `appinv.aspx` page. When running addin, Visual Studio tries to grant permissions to the app first, but because of error, it's not able to grant required permissions.

I can recommend you to open Internet Explorer, press Ctrl+Shift+Del and delete everything - cookies, temp data, etc.
Then reopen your project and try to deploy again.

Comment: Thanks Kai.
The restart worked.

However, now the problem is that, the app does not seem to be able to access the specified list in the HostWeb, though I have duly assigned the Read permissions to site collection.

It gives me the message "Access Denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."

Any thoughts.

Comment: Did you trust the app during the deployment?

Comment: No I only added the permissions in AppManifest.
How do you trust the app.

I am only debugging the app as of now, by pressing F5.

Comment: Try to completely remove the app (retract), then deploy it once again.

Comment: Retracted and redeployed, but the issue still remains the same,
Still the app cannot access the List on the HostWeb. 

It gives the following message - **"Access Denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."**

Comment: That's really strange, I can advice the following. Retract the app once again, and temporary set permissions to full control over site collection. Also in code make sure you are not using some other services like user profiles, search, taxonomy, etc. in this case you need to add separate permissions.